# Php Curl Login Cookie return error that no cookie

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I have a site where i try to login, cookies are set and saved to file, but after i send postfiend to login page, website redirect me to a page where warring me that cookies are not enabled.

```
$post = "Username=".$user."&password=".$pswd."&loginButton=1";
$options = array(
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)',
  CURLOPT_POST => true, //using post
  CURLOPT_URL => $address,  //where to go
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post, //input params
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, //Returns a string value of the request
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, //Avoid SSL problems
  CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
  CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true,
  //CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookies.txt',
  CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookie.txt', //Save cookies
  CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
); //Cookies located

$ch = curl_init(); //Initialize curl in $ch
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options); //add params values to $ch
$content = curl_exec($ch); //execute

echo $content;
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually this happens because the site sets those required cookies on a previous page, like perhaps the page that shows the login form.

One way to detect this is to flush your browser cookies and the navigate the web site with your browser and investigate when exactly the cookies are sent from the server the first time.

Comment: even with cookies what i save from my browser, it forward me to error page after sending postfields